# How to do a bootable full backup of Debian root server to a cloud drive

Tags: debian, backup, ftp, raid1

In the past I was running a server with RAID-1 and experienced the phenomenon that both drives were damaged at the same time (while in holidays).

I had a backup of my data partition, but with that of course I am not able to rebuild a running and bootable system.

After replacing the drives my data center didn't offer the old debian versions anymore I was using before the crash. So they installed a newer debian version and I had to install and configure everything from scratch.

So there is my question:
How can i run a full backup with all partitions and transfer it to a cloud drive (via FTP for example) to be able in future to recreate the whole system?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 - | \
ssh -o Compression=no -x user@my-data-center dd of=full-disk-backup.gz
```

Or, if you want `ftp`, maybe mount it at `/tmp` and do the `dd` as usual, as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem).